# What should I know before stepping into orchestral/ fantasy music composition?

Tags: theory, composition, orchestration

I have completed grade 7 in music theory (Trinity College London syllabus). Due to certain unavoidable circumstances, I have to self-study music hereafter. My passion is to become an independent music composer. What all concepts I need to cover to compose good orchestral and fantasy epic music? Please could you provide me with the resources and the book names?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome! Please take a look at the [topics that are covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). In particular, requests for outside resources are not covered, but even without that, this would probably be too broad a question. One tip, though: self-study doesn't have to mean "having no outside input." Find people to ask for feedback!

Comment: What many of the famous composers did was to choose a score, copy it over and try to understand the why of everything in it.  If you haven't done that, maybe it would be helpful.  I'm not speaking from experience -- I have never done that -- but I don't have a talent or interest in composing.

Answer (score 2):

The main thing you should know is that

**1.  Many of the greatest musical pieces and also texts about how to do four part harmony are in the public domain**.

If you're willing to search for it, you can find enough source material to study for the rest of your life.

This is not necessarily the best example, but it's one that I found within about 10 seconds after a Google search for "public domain four part harmony"

https://www.loc.gov/resource/muspre1800.101000/?sp=6

**2.  Bach's chorales, which are obviously public domain, are the purest expression of SATB harmony, so you should start with those.**

https://www.pjb.com.au/mus/arr/us/satb_chorales.pdf

**3.  Music theorists absolutely live for showing how smart they are by making YouTube videos**. Type almost any keyword into YouTube, and you'll get plenty of help. Here's an example chosen randomly.

**4.  Not only is technology improving a lot, but companies are using new models for pricing sound libraries.** A library that I use that costs just 10s of dollars per month his east West's sound library.  Here's an example of a random (to me) person playing around with some of that package. I think if you watch it, you'll see that the only limitation to modern orchestral composers is their own ability and imagination.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t have to know anything in particular, you could dive in and learn from your mistakes.

Some things that would be very helpful to know are:

- Orchestration
- Polyphony, homophony, etc.
- Compositional forms (invention, fugue, canon, sonata-allegro, minuet and trio, dances, etc, etc)
- Instruments and music theories from around the world (not just Western Europe)
- Pop and jazz arrangement
- Synthesis and electronic music production
- Music technology
- How to play (at a basic level) as many instruments as possible
- Musical acoustics
- Audio engineering

Those are roughly in order of importance but the music you hear in your head may require more knowledge in some areas than in others, and in different priorities.

Any resource recommendations would be off topic here, so I’m ignoring that part of your question. You can use the keywords I have listed above to do web searches for resources.